# Доступ разных подсетей

Tags: администрирование, windows-server, маршрутизация

Есть основная подсеть с диапазоном адресов:

```
192.168.100.x
```

Внутри этой сети есть шлюз доступный по адресу:

```
192.168.100.3 (2 сетевые карты. Внутренняя и внешняя сеть. Zentyal)
```

Так же есть Dell сервер с 4 сетевыми картами:
1 - Локальная сеть (192.168.100.6, Windows server 2012r2)
2 - Отдана под Hyper-v
3 - Отдельным кабелем уходит в другой коммутатор (192.168.2.2)
4 - отключена.

Смысл вопроса:
Необходимо настроить маршрутизацию на NIC 3 таким образом, что бы подсети

```
192.168.100.x и 192.168.2.x
```

могли общаться между собой и подсеть 192.168.2.x могла выходить в интернет. Но шлюз и эта подсеть не соединены одним проводом.
Я установил компонент Remote Access со всеми зависимостями. Создал статический маршрут:

Назначение 192.168.2.0

Подсеть 255.255.255.0

Шлюз 192.168.100.3

Интерфейс указал сетевую карту под номером 3 с адресом 192.168.2.2

При попытке пинговать любой адрес той подсети я получаю сообщение о том, что превышен интервал ожидания запроса.
Где я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно понимаете ритуал прописывания маршрута. Тому серверу, где стоят 4 сетевые карты, ваши маршруты не нужны - он и так уже все знает. Все, что нужно на нем сделать - это разрешить маршрутизацию (гуглите именно по таким ключевым словам).

Маршруты же вам потребуется прописать на *каждый* компьютер из 2й и 100й подсетей. Общий принцип добавления маршрутов - *когда некоторый узел становится маршрутизатором, надо об этом рассказать его соседям.* В вашем случае нужно:

1. Компьютерам из 2й подсети надо рассказать, что внешний мир им доступен через ваш сервер. То есть им надо прописать основной шлюз 192.168.2.2
2. Компьютерам из 100й подсети надо рассказать, что 2я подсеть им доступна через ваш сервер. То есть надо прописать им маршрут до 192.168.2.0 через 192.168.100.6
3. И, наконец, последний пункт - маршрутизатору, который 192.168.100.3, тоже нужен маршрут до подсети 192.168.2.0

Пункт 3 проще выполнить "ручками". Пункты 1-2 делаются через DHCP-сервер этой сети. Я не знаю, какой сервер вы используете - поэтому как прописывать маршруты вам также надо будет гуглить.